# How to set custom labels on X axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have function:

```
qplot(gender, salary, data = uof)
```

How can I set custom labels on X axis? There you can
[check picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY0Bm.png)

---

For example i would like to turn 0.00 on X axis to "rabbit" and 1.00 on X axis to "elephant"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gender is currently a numeric variable.

`uof$gender = as.character(uof$gender)`

`uof$gender[uof$gender == 0] = 'rabbit'`

`uof$gender[uof$gender == 1] = 'elephant'`

`qplot(gender, salary, data = uof)`

Comment: Don't have error, but it doesn't show correct on plot:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/5duyT3qDTE29JUMc6_vcHw.png

Comment: how many genders are there in total? the change (ex: from 0 to rabbit) must be made for all levels.